# How do you force Facebook to refresh a cached image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

We have a logo that was replaced last week, but Facebook is still using the old image during shares. I've used the Facebook Object Debugger to try to refresh the image; when I choose "Show existing scrape information", Facebook displays a 206 response code and a warning that "og:image could not be downloaded or is too small".

Here is the url in question: https://images.go2advertising.com/hooked-logo.jpg

In the "When shared, this is what will be included" section, the proper image is displayed. However, in the "Type of Share" section or when clicking "See this in the share dialog" the old image is displayed. We can't simply change the url since this is initiated from an app.

When I click "Fetch new scrape information", I am told that "Errors must be fixed":
Can't Download / Could not retrieve data from URL.
However, if I change the casing in the url (e.g. use a capital H) Facebook still complains that it couldn't download the image, but in the Type of Share and Share Dialog the new image is displayed, so it obviously CAN download the image.

I will also note that I think the "Can't Download" error is not a real error since I get that when I try ANY image (random images from other sites, for example).

Comment: What kind of shares are you talking about? Are you using OpenGraph objects, which use this image?

Comment: We are using the Feed dialog in the iOS and Android SDK's. However, the image shown in the Share dialog that can be accessed from Facebook's object debugger [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) is also incorrect.